# SUM cells based on their left cell's condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My Google Sheets has many columns. Data is organized in pairs. One cell is date and another is number. I want to get a SUM of all the cells where their pair is a specific date.

[image: example]

For example, in the above image, I want to sum all the values of the day `03/24`. I expect the result: 6+13+36 = 55.

How can I do that in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIF with same size but offset ranges:

```
=SUMIF(B2:F13,"03/24",C2:G13)
```